# why is the python code rejecting integer numbers?

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I wrote a code

```
import re
inp=input("Please enter the file name ")
if len(inp)<1: inp = 'regex_sum_109744.txt'
fh=open(inp,'r')
sum=c=0
for i in fh:
    i=i.rstrip()
    s=re.findall('[0-9]+',i)
    for j in s:
        try:
            u=float(s[c])
        except:
            #print("the thing is",j)
            continue
        sum=sum+u
        #print("**********","the number is ",u,"the sum is ",sum,"************")
        c=c+1
    c=0
print(sum)
```

but when I change [0-9] to [0-9.] the output starts rejecting the integers

[i have uploaded an image in which you can see that along with dot(.) the integers 3 and 4 are also rejected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9em67.png)

Can someone please explain me why is this happening?

Comment: Note `[0-9.]+` will match 1+ digits and dots.

Comment: whatfor is `s[c]` ... ? this `u=float(s[c])` should probably  be `u=float(j)` and `c` is obsolete

Comment: If you uncomment the `print` line in your `except` block, what strings are causing the exceptions? Matching all digits and dots will match some non-number values, such as dots by themselves (which are probably periods in text, rather than decimal points).

Comment: Use `(?:\d+(?:\.\d*)?|\.\d+)`

Comment: when I use [0-9.]+ , as you can see I put a print statement in the except block to see what will be rejected, the program also rejects the integers along with dot.

Comment: I mean it only converts floating point numbers to float and rejects integers. Why?

Comment: @Blckknght as soon as I type [0-9] instead of [0-9.] it starts converting integers too. Otherwise it was only converting the floating numbers and integers were taken as an exception just like dot (.) .

Comment: Please provide an example input that can be used to reproduce the issue. We don't have a copy of your file, so we can't see the same problem you're seeing.

Comment: @Blckknght http://py4e-data.dr-chuck.net/regex_sum_42.txt

Comment: @Blckknght you can also refer to the image which I just mentioned in the post. ThankYou

Answer (score 0):

Your issue has to do with the fact that you're trying to convert `s[c]` to a float, but you never increment `c` if it can't be done (you `continue` before you get to the  `c=c+1` line). This means that after the first match that fails to convert, you'll keep trying the same `s[c]` for the rest of the inner loop, and keep on failing. So you will never match a number that appears on a line after a period. The error reporting doesn't help you because it prints `j`, which still updates as the loop runs.

It's not clear at all to me why you're doing `s[c]` and `c=c+1` at all when you already have a `for` loop over the values in the `s` list. Just try to convert `j` instead of `s[c]` and it should work (you can then drop `c` from your code completely). You could also put a copy of the `c=c+1` line in the `except` block, but I really wouldn't recommend that. Indeed, I'd suggest that you narrow the `except` a bit more, so that you only handle `ValueError` exceptions, or even use a more complicated regex that won't match the periods in your text, so you don't need the `try`/`except` at all.